# ld: file not found: -fobjc-arc clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) Error?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, linker

when i used Parse and Facebook framework I get the Error like,

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/netdroid-apple/Desktop/Viivox/Viivox2912/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK, missing required architecture x86_64 in file /Users/netdroid-apple/Desktop/Viivox/Viivox2912/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK (3 slices)

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_FBTokenInformationExpirationDateKey", referenced from:
      -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy cacheTokenInformation:] in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
      -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy expirationDate] in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
      -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy setExpirationDate:] in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
  "_FBTokenInformationTokenKey", referenced from:
      -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy accessToken] in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
      -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy setAccessToken:] in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
  "_FBTokenInformationUserFBIDKey", referenced from:
      -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy facebookId] in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
      -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy setFacebookId:] in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_BFExecutor", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFUser.o)
      objc-class-ref in Parse(Parse.o)
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFCommandCache.o)
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFPinningEventuallyQueue.o)
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFEventuallyQueue.o)
      objc-class-ref in Parse(BFTask+Private.o)
      l_OBJC_$_CATEGORY_BFExecutor_$_Background in Parse(BFTask+Private.o)
      ...
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_BFTask", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFFile.o)
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFUser.o)
      objc-class-ref in Parse(Parse.o)
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFBlockRetryer.o)
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFCommandCache.o)
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFConfig.o)
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFEventuallyPin.o)
      ...
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_BFTaskCompletionSource", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookAuthenticationProvider.o)
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFNetworkCommandRunner.o)
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFObject.o)
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFOfflineStore.o)
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFTaskHTTPRequestOperation.o)
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFEventuallyQueue.o)
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFSQLiteDatabase.o)
      ...
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBAppCall", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookAuthenticationProvider.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBRequest", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookAuthenticationProvider.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBRequestConnection", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in UserLoginViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBSession", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookAuthenticationProvider.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBSessionTokenCachingStrategy", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_FBSessionTokenCachingStrategy", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

After that i use Flag  " -force_load "  in other linker flag and get the below error

```
ld: file not found: `-fobjc-arc`

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have seen lots of answer of stackoverflow but not get the exact solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your Facebook framework does not include the x86_64 architecture. Build it for all of the architectures you intend to use.

You are also passing a linker flag in such a way that the linker is interpreting -fobjc- arc as a file name.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same error because I had forgotten to import the Bolts framework, once copied to project and added import statement to header file it compiled no problem.

Also I did not check 'Copy' when importing the bolt framework into project and had moved it from it's original location.